# Getx() and hide bottomnavigation bar - error with stateful widget rendering

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a stateful widget ([miniplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer)) in my stateless widget. I am trying to hide the bottomnavigation bar and getting the below error when I use Obx... Any idea how to fix this?

I/flutter ( 9567): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9567): The following assertion was thrown building ValueListenableBuilder(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter ( 9567): [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#87424], _InheritedTheme], state:
I/flutter ( 9567): _ValueListenableBuilderState#23ae3):
I/flutter ( 9567): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter ( 9567): This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process
I/flutter ( 9567): of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if
I/flutter ( 9567): one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds
I/flutter ( 9567): parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the
I/flutter ( 9567): framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
I/flutter ( 9567): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter ( 9567):   Obx
I/flutter ( 9567): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
I/flutter ( 9567):   ValueListenableBuilder
I/flutter ( 9567):
I/flutter ( 9567): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 9567):   **Miniplayer**

Code for bottomnavigation

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: Obx(
            () => !_videoController.showBottomNavigation.value
                ? SizedBox.shrink()
                : BottomNavigationBar(
                    currentIndex: 0,
                    fixedColor: Colors.blue,
                    items: [
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                        label: 'Home',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                        label: 'Messages',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        label: 'Profile',
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare bool condition with *isTrue* or *isFalse*. Then wrapping the UI changes.

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: Obx(
            (){ return _videoController.showBottomNavigation.isFalse
                ? SizedBox.shrink()
                : BottomNavigationBar(
                    currentIndex: 0,
                    fixedColor: Colors.blue,
                    items: [
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                        label: 'Home',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                        label: 'Messages',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        label: 'Profile',
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
          }),
```